# Python - pickle pickles cached_property

Tags: python, properties, pickle

I have a Python class containing a `cached_property`, which I intend to be computed in runtime only.

When I pickle this class, the cached property is pickled as well, and since the property is read only, I can't change its value to `None`.

Why does pickle pickles properties if they should be computed at runtime?
How can I prevent pickle from pickling the cached property?

Answer (score 1):

Pickle uses `__getstate__` to get the object attributes (see [their docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__)). By default `obj.__getstate__()` returns `obj.__dict__`, which contains the cached properties. So, you can override this method to clean up this cache before returning the state:

```py
class MyClass:
  @cached_property
  def foo(self, *args):
    ...

  def __getstate__(self):
    state = self.__dict__.copy()
    state.pop("foo", None)
    return state
```